# How can I write this regex to match the entire string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which is made up of 3 lower case characters separated by underscores.  These are all valid examples:

```
abc
abc_def
abc_def_ghi
```

These are not:

```
abc_
abc_ab
abc_123
```

I wrote a regex:

```
>>> def test_string(test):
...    import re
...    pc = re.compile("[a-z]{3}(_[a-z]{3})*")
...    if pc.match(test):
...        return True
...    else:
...        return False
...
>>> print test_string('abc')
True    # Okay
>>> print test_string('ab')
False   # Okay
>>> print test_string('abc_')
True    # Not Okay
```

but it doesn't exclude the cases I don't want.

*How can I write a function to test that the strings are of the form I'd like, and not of the form I don't want?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to add the end of line anchor `$` in your regex:

```
re.compile("[a-z]{3}(_[a-z]{3})*$")
```

This makes sure there's nothing else after what is matched has been matched.

You won't need the beginning of line anchor (`^`) because `match` by default tries to match at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Of course.  Thanks.  And the `^` at the beginning would be a good idea too.

Comment: I tried testing that Python requires that matches start at the beginning of the string but couldn't find a fiddle site that confirmed that. Can you point me to either a fiddle site or documentation that would let me confirm this for myself? Thanks.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Sure, check [this](http://ideone.com/dmQxia) out. Also, in [the doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match), "If zero or more characters at the **beginning** of string match ..."

Comment: Yes, `re.match()` automatically anchors to the start of the string; making it explicit doesn't hurt though.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add anchor characters so that you match the beginning and end of the string, as in:

```
^[a-z]{3}(_[a-z]{3})*$
```

Update: `^` anchor is superfluous in Python in this context, as pointed out by @Jerry in other answer.

Comment: You were below the fold.  I saw your answer after I comments on Jerry's.

Comment: Yeah, that happens as a result of SO's AJAX updates posting the most recent first. Oldest answers get pushed down.